# Can I filter Drive emails by doc ID?

Tags: google-drive, gmail-filters

I want to filter all Drive comment notification emails for a couple particular docs to get a particular label? Is this possible?

I had hoped that either searching for the 34-character ID from the URL would match the email since there are links to Drive from the email, but for some reason that doesn't match no matter how I quote it. The doc title alone isn't unique enough for a reliable filter in this case.

The email metadata for these looks something like

```
Subject: Taco party p... - +someuser@example.com Could you clarif...
From: "Jennifer (Google Sheets)" <comments-noreply@docs.google.com>
Body:
Jennifer added a comment to the following document
Taco party planning (<doc URL>)
<comment and details>
…
```

Comment: I'd say the most important part of this question is that "The doc title alone isn't unique enough".

Comment: Why? You're saying the solution should just be rename my and other people's docs to something I can match in filters? And really it's that the truncated _prefix_ of the title that shows up in the subject line isn't unique enough, which happens a lot when you only have 2 or 3 words of entropy to work with.

Comment: I'm just saying that the solution would be easy if you could use the title of the e-mail. I'm not saying you should change the name of the doc.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the subject alone doesn't seem like a reliable signal to me which is why I was looking for something based on the doc ID. Edited the question to add a concrete example for reference, although there are a few different types of email notifications you can get for a doc that all look a little different that make it especially challenging.

Comment: The from address would be different to the reply-to address. Does Google use the same from address for different docs?

Comment: Fair question. The reply-to is a long hash like `d+xyz123XYZzyx321ZYX-aAa123BbB456cCc78987y98y7a2f897ya9aWEFiuW9aaw98hfwaLKUawe@docs.google.com`.